# How to make a coin counter give me the amount of coins I put in

Tags: loops

So for this proble, double amount is a randomized number with 2 decimals, like 1.41. My job is to cheack how many coins go into it. so that would be 5 quarters, 1 dime, 1 nickle and 1 penny. so adding all that up would be 8 as the answer.

```
              public static int Test7(double amount)
        {
            double answer =1;
            for (int i =0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                if (amount >= 0.25)
                {
                    answer = amount / 0.25;
                }
                else if (amount >= 0.10)
                {
                    answer = amount / 0.10;
                }
                else if (amount >= 0.05)
                {
                    answer = amount / 0.05;
                }
                else if (amount >= 0.01)
                {
                    answer = amount - 0.01;
                }
            }
            return (int)answer;
        }
```

This code would output the answer as 5 as i believe the way i set it up does not continue the chain down the list and just gives me the first answer.

I tried to use a while loop and it broke the program.

Comment: Your first issue is that the answer consists of 4 values (total quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies), but your function is returning a single value. Think about how you would model the return value to return something other than an `int` and see where that leads you.

Comment: so should i throw the whole thing into a while amount !=0 loop?